# How to rectify Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\mb_detect_encoding() after installing composer?

Tags: php, ubuntu-21.04

I am using ubuntu 21.04 in that i installed composer by using this command  `sudo apt-get install composer` ,after installing i type `composer` it's showing following error

```
HP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\mb_detect_encoding() in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Descriptor/TextDescriptor.php(329): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Helper::strlen('h')
#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Descriptor/TextDescriptor.php(97): Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\TextDescriptor->calculateTotalWidthForOptions(Array)
#2 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Descriptor/TextDescriptor.php(197): Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\TextDescriptor->describeInputDefinition(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition), Array)
#3 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Descriptor/Descriptor.php(55): Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\TextDescriptor->describeApplication(Object(Composer\Console\Application), Array)
#4 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/DescriptorHelper.php(67): Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\Descriptor->describ in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php on line 50
```

please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 22):

You simply enable mbstring extension it will remove the uncaught error

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
```

Comment: For php 7.4 , use ```sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring``` .. Similarly replace the version number in comand based on current php version installed in machine.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using **PHP 7.4**:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I encountered this issue on php8.2 while the stack trace differs from OP  doing as mentionned by @MiraTech @user16784870 or @Jay-Teli fixed this error :

```
sudo apt-get install php8.2-mbstring
```

Comment: Or just `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` to get package related to currently used version (php --version)

Comment: It's possible that the solution you provided is correct. However, I would need to verify this again if I were to work on the PHP project again, as it is unclear whether the command you recommended would work with the specific version of PHP used in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Check [`phpinfo.php`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.phpinfo.php) for `ctype` module information. In my case, it wasn't loaded and I didn't see the following:

[image: ctype module loaded]

I activated it in `php.ini` (location depends on your configuration):

```
;extension=curl
extension=ctype # uncomment or add this
;extension=ffi
```

and restart php service. You should see `ctype` module's block and error should  go away.